Equality in several variables
I arrive at the below identity by experimentation. I thought of proving it, but I did not find the right approach. I attempted Lagrange Interpolation method, because it looks so close in its formatting, but it did not yield for me yet.

QUESTION. Let $e_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1+\cdots+x_n$. Is this true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n  x_k\, \prod_{i\neq k}^{1,n} \frac{x_k+y x_i}{x_k-x_i} = e_1(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$


It holds for $y=-1$ by inspection. Henceforth suppose $y\ne -1$. Consider the function
$$f(z) = z \frac{1}{z+yz}
\prod_{p=1}^n \frac{z+yx_p}{z-x_p}
= \frac{1}{1+y}
\prod_{p=1}^n \frac{z+yx_p}{z-x_p}.$$
Here we have that
$$\;\underset{z=x_q}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= x_q \prod_{p=1, p\ne q}^n \frac{x_q+yx_p}{x_q-x_p}.$$
Residues sum to zero so the target sum must equal minus
the residue at infinity, which is
$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{1+y}
\prod_{p=1}^n \frac{1/z+yx_p}{1/z-x_p} 
= \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{1+y}
\prod_{p=1}^n \frac{1+zyx_p}{1-zx_p}.$$
We have
$$\left(\prod_{p=1}^n \frac{1+zyx_p}{1-zx_p}\right)'
= \prod_{p=1}^n \frac{1+zyx_p}{1-zx_p}
\left(\sum_{p=1}^n \frac{yx_p}{1+zyx_p}
+ \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{x_p}{1-zx_p}\right).$$
Set $z=0$ to get
$$\frac{1}{1+y} \left(\sum_{p=1}^n y x_p
+ \sum_{p=1}^n x_p\right) = \sum_{p=1}^n x_p$$
as claimed.
This proof  goes through with the  $x_p$ being distinct
non-zero  integers.  We  then have  equality for  $x_p$
variables because  the original becomes an  equality in
polynomials   upon  multiplication   by  $\prod_{p=1}^n
\prod_{r=p+1}^n (x_p-x_r).$
